# после успешного завершение потока Task какая функция выполняется

Tags: c#

после успешного завершение потока Task какая функция выполняется в главном потоке, и какой синтаксис имеет . если не успешно то этот функция не будет работать. ?

Comment: Эээ... «после успешного завершение потока Task» — а почему у Task есть отдельный поток, который вместе с ним завершается? и почему что-то в этот момент должно выполняться в главном потоке?

Comment: Та, которая сделала `await` из главного потока?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Если в главном потоке нету цикла сообщений, то результат может быть неожиданным.

Comment: @VladD, а у нас вообще есть вариант, когда в главном потоке нет цикла сообщения? Вроде как раз тот поток главным и считается, в котором цикл сообщений есть? Или я в терминологии запутался?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, если у нас консольная программа, например. При этом все await'ы возвращаются на thread pool.